# How to set up Gitlab CI for a .NET HTTP Server and testing with Python?

Tags: python, asp.net, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm working on a Project where I'm trying to setup a HTTP Server in C#. The responds from the server are tested using the `pytest` Module.
This is what I've done so far:

- Define the API using swagger editor
- generate base code using swagger generator
- write some `python` Tests which are sending requests to the server and testing whether or not the responds fulfill certain requirements

I now want to set up CI on gitlab before I start actually writing the functions that correspond to the routes I've defined earlier. I set up a Runner on my local machine (it's later going to be on a dedicated server) using Docker.
As I am new to CI, there are a few questions I'm struggling with:

- As I need both Python and .NET for testing, should I choose .NET as a base image and then install Python or Python as base image and then install .NET? What would be easier? I tried the latter but it doesn't seem very elegant...
- Do I build before I push to the remote repository and include the `/bin` folder in my repository to execute those files or would I rather build during the CI and therefore not have to push anything but sourcecode?

I know those questions are a little bit wild but as I am new to CI and also Docker I'm looking for advise on how to follow best practices (if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

The base image for a runner is just the default if you don't specify one in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. You can override the runner's default image by using a "pipeline default" image at the top of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (outside of any jobs), or you can specify the image for each job individually.

Using a "pipeline default" image:

```yaml
image: python:latest

stages:
  - build
...
```

In this example, all jobs will use the `python:latest` image unless the job specifies its own image like this example:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test

Build Job:
  stage: build
  image: python:latest
  script:
    - ...
```

Here, this job overrides the runner's default.

```yaml
image: python:latest

stages:
  - build
  - db_setup

Build Job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - # run some build steps

Database Setup Job:
  stage: db_setup
  image: mysql:latest
  script:
    - mysql -h my-host.example.com -u my-user -pmy-password -e "create database my-database;"
```

In this example, we have a "pipeline default" image that the "Build Job" uses since it doesn't specify its own image, but the "Database Setup Job" uses the `mysql:latest` image.

Here's an example where the runner's default image is `ruby:latest`

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test

Build Job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - # run some build steps

Test Job:
  stage: test
  image: golang:latest
  script:
    - # run some tests
```

In this last example, the "Build Job" uses the runner's base image, `ruby:latest`, but the "Test Job" uses `golang:latest`.

For you second question, it's up to you but the convention is to only commit source code and not dependencies/compiled resources, but again it's just a convention.
build:

Comment: Does that mean, that each job is a separate process and I that they can communicate with each other? So I would set up a job for starting the server and another for starting the test script?

Comment: No, when using the docker executor, all the jobs run in their own, isolated, docker container that's spun up when the job starts, and is terminated when the job finishes. I don't have direct experience with the other executors, but in general, communication between these jobs isn't a role for CI/CD.

Comment: But how would you then test the response made to a request to the server? The only option I see is to run the server and the testing in a single job, for which I am unable to find an elegant solution or example...

Comment: I interpreted your tests as static tests against the code base, not against the running application. To test the running app, it will depend on how you would normally deploy it. For me, I deploy a web app in a qa environment in one job, then run my browser tests (using headless chrome) against the running app in another. You'll have to figure out what works best for your tests and you app.